# Format external SD card from android

Tags: external-sd, formatting

I am having issues with my SD card, it just gets on getting unmounted and mounted many times per day. I have read online that the best thing to do is to format my card.

I've looked online and everywhere it is suggested that I use the built-in format function found in "Settings > Storage > Unmount SD card + Format SD card" but the option "Format SD card" never shows.

This is what I have before and after unmounting:

```
 Before Unmounting          After Unmounting
```

[image: Before_Screenshot]   [image: After_Screenshot]

<sub>Screenshots - (Click to enlarge)</sub>

I also tried to format from linux (I am an Ubuntu user) and I got some error (both in gnome disk util and gparted).

Further info:

My question is then: How can I format my external sd card? I don't have a card reader.

Wiko Darkmoon
Custom rom: superdragonpt_v1.0 from xda, 4.2.2, kernel 3.4.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format an SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7576/how-to-format-an-sd-card)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Erase SD card" formats it. Back up data before formatting, because all of the files are deleted. You can format from the PC aswell, by mounting as Mass Storage, and formatting it like an regular USB.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware that erase would format it. Cheers